# Variables containing "." character in Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars templates. If I want to insert a variable in an hbs file, I add it as `{{var_name}}`.

The issue is, I have a large object with its keys taking formats similar to:

```
{
    "stats.name":"John",
    "stats.performance.day":123,
    "stats.performance.month":4567,
    "company":"My LLC"
}
```

If I try to add these to the Handlebars file as `{{company}}, {{stats.name}}, {{stats.performance.day}}, {{stats.performance.month}}` then only the `{{company}}` will be displayed. All other values come out blank, I assume because "." is a special character in Handlebars.

My question is, is there a way to override this, or do I actually need to iterate through this object and change every "." to a "_" or something before passing it to Handlebars to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend renaming your properties. [Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) is one of the two ways to access object properties in JavaScript. Typical code would look like: `obj.prop`. If your object's keys are *not* valid [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier), then you must use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation): `obj['my-prop']`. Since a dot is a property accessor, it is very unusual to see one in a property name. If I were to come across code written as `obj['stats.performance.date']`, I would assume it was a mistake and that `obj.stats.performance.date` was intended.

With that said, Handlebars *does* support referencing properties that are not valid identifiers. This is called ["segment-literal-notation"](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#basic-blocks), and it is as simple as wrapping square brackets around your identifier:

```
{{[stats.performance.day]}}
```

The documentation also states that:

> JavaScript-style strings, " and ', may also be used vs. [ pairs.

So the following alternatives are valid:

```
{{"stats.performance.day"}}
{{'stats.performance.day'}}
```